How to align some lines to a specific alignment, and some other lines to another specific alignment, where some lines has justified text?
See the following:


First line has the question "What is wrong ...?", it starts from the specified margin in latex, that is 2 cm.
Then 2nd, 4th, 6th, 8th, and 10th lines all start from same position. Furthermore, 3rd, 5th, 7th, and 9th lines all start from the same position. In the end, we have the 11th line, it starts from the same position as the 10th line.
The 10th and 11th lines have justified text. Meaning that the word "has" has reached to the end of the line.

How can I do that, where, as you can see, I use mathematical expressions.

My attempt: (FAILED TO BE GOOD):
For some parts of my document, I wrote things like this:

and this is totally fine, with the word "if" is aligned. But for that I used
\begin{cases}
 & \text{ if } x= 
\end{cases}

I tried to avoid the curly bracket, and adjust the number of rows and columns, but then it looked weird and the text is not justified because it is considered as math input, even if we use \text{ }, because that is inside $ $.

Your help would be appreciated. THANKS!

The following is a simple way to achieve what you're after, setting the mathematical expression in an align, and using \qquad to push content to the right.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

Which is wrong with the following argument?
\begin{align*}
  & \qquad \text{Let~$R$ be the real numbers} \\
  & \text{For all $x, y \in R$, $f(x) + f(y) = f(xy)$} \\
  & \qquad \text{is equivalent to} \\
  & \text{For all $x, y \in R$, $f(-x) + f(y) = f((-x)y)$} \\
  & \qquad \text{which is equivalent to} \\
  & \text{For all $x, y \in R$, $f(-x) + f(y) = f((-x)y) = f(x(-y)) = f(x) + f(-y)$} \\
  & \qquad \text{From this for $y = 0$, we make the conclusion} \\
  & \text{For all $x \in R$, $f(-x) = f(x)$} \\
  & \qquad \parbox{0.9\linewidth}{Since the steps are reversible, any function with the fourth property has
                                  the first property. Therefore, for all $x, y \in R$, $\cos(x) + \cos(y) = \cos(xy)$}
\end{align*}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}

